# send message to rabbitmq with http request

Tags: javascript, jquery, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm newbie on rabbitmq and I developed a project based on spring & rabbitmq & AMQP.

I created a Produce.class to create request and put them into rabbitmq based on AMQP and Consumer.class to get message from rabbitmq and process it with java.

now I wanna know is it possible to put the same message with http request.
(I create sample web page and I use jquery as client side framework)

I googled but I can't find something usefull.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RabbitMQ web-stomp plug-in](http://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html)

You have to enable the plug-in using:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_web_stomp
```

Then restart rabbitmq server.

Test the plugin using: `http://127.0.0.1:15674/stomp`, you should see:
**Welcome to SockJS!**

And as you can see from the web site you can use directly the page:

```
<script src="http://cdn.sockjs.org/sockjs-0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="stomp.js"></script>
<script>
```

You can download the stomp.js here :https://raw.github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/master/lib/stomp.js